# Extract unique value from the range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I would like to extract the unique value from my range in Excel. This value will shift between the columns in this range.
[image]

Between the N/A values I have got the proper address, which I would like to have populated in the cell pointed below.

For this purpose I tried the UNIQUE function:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function

```
  =unique(U3:U6)
```

which gave me the #NAME value.

I also tried the other code from here:

https://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html

exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list

trumpexcel.com/unique-items-from-a-list-in-excel/

with INDEX:MATCH function

```
   =IFERROR(INDEX($U$3:$U$6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($U$3:UE,$U$3:$U$6),0)),"")
```

I also got nothing.

I also tried with IF statement also:

```
     =IF(U3:U6,"N/A+N/A+N/A","")
```

but I don't know how to extract the cell with other value, than stated in the formula.

The combination of function INDEX:MATCH with COUNTIF also doesn't work

```
  =INDEX(List,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(U3:$U$6,List)+(COUNTIF(List,List)<>1),0))
```

How can I make my unique value visible in the cell below? How can I exclude all not valid records in this range?

Comment: What Excel version and subscription are you using? (I believe the Unique function is only available in 365 for Current Channel subscribers) - the unique solutions should work just fine, but if you have a simi-annual subscription, you will have to wait to July to use it (about time it came)... btw: what is the'E' doing in the countif part ("$U$3:UE") of your index:match formula?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016. In my understanding, I should set some statement including the non "N/A" value, which will be automatically excluded giving me the clear result in the target cell.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with using worksheet functions like `UNIQUE()` is portability.  Only recent versions of Excel support them.  Another option is to use a VBA User Defined Function.  Even Paleozoic versions of Excel support VBA *(all you need to do is make sure macros are enabled)*

Here is a typical UDF to return unique values:

```
Public Function unikue(rng As Range)
    Dim arr, c As Collection, r As Range
    Dim nCall As Long, nColl As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set c = New Collection

    nCall = Application.Caller.Count

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In rng
            c.Add r.Text, CStr(r.Text)
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    nColl = c.Count


    If nCall > nColl Then
        ReDim arr(1 To nCall, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To nCall
            arr(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To nColl, 1 To 1)
    End If

    For i = 1 To nColl
        arr(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    unikue = arr
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** this UDF in the worksheet:

1. hi-light a block of cells in some column
2. click in the Formula Bar
3. type:  `=UNIKUE(U3:U6)`
4. finish with Cntrl-Shft-ENTER rather than just the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Your hint is good, but I am still getting the #NAME instead of the result. I know how to install function in VBA, so I did all the steps, which you showed me. Is there something missing here maybe?

Comment: @MKR  the ***#NAME?*** error means Excel can't find the function! ...................make sure you put it in a ***Standard Module***

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Excel 2016 you will not get the unique or filter functions that would solve your issue. So we will try something else.

EDIT:
Step wise approach with explicit dynamic named range:

1. Create a dynamic named range:
   Go to Formulas -> Name Manager -> and click New... 
   Enter List as the name and in the Refers to: enter:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$U$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$U:$U)-2,1)
```

This assumes:

a) your list starts in sheet1 cell U3 [if not, then change the Sheet1!$U$3 to the first row of your list and Sheet1!$U:$U to the column of your list]

b) you have inputs in the two first rows (U1 and U2) as in your screen dump [if not change the '-2' to minus the number of rows with inputs]

By building a dynamic named range, you can append as many rows as you wish without changing your formula.

2. Enter the Index:Match formula:

If your unique list range start in cell V24, enter this formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(List,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($V$23:$V23,List),0)),"")
```

If your list starts in a different cell, you need to change '$V$23:$V23' accordingly. Just remember that the row in this expression '$V$23:$V23' need to reflect the row **above** the cell you enter it into (otherwise you will get a circular reference-error). And make sure you do not enter a '$' sign before the second '23'(otherwise your list will return 0 in each row).

3. Drag the list down and it should populate with unique values.

... I still cannot figure out a way to avoid having 'N/A+N/A+N/A' show up once. Perhaps someone else have a suggestion(?)

Comment: When I use your code i.e. in the cell V24 and typing:  =IFERROR(INDEX(List,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($V$22:$V23,List),0)),""), I am getting nothing. The same as in previous code... I don't need to engage the V15 and V16, since I want to have the result in one cell only.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you use it in V24, the formula should be =IFERROR(INDEX(List,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($V$23:$V23,List),0)),"") - my bad - But either way: The formula is intended to return a range with unique values from a different range. How will you fit that into one cell if it returns several unique values?

Comment: I would love to use your code, but once I put your first formula to the cell V23 I got 0, when I did it for the cell V24 I got a blank cell 23.

Comment: Ok. I tried to make it clear. Try following the steps above. - if the cells I have assumed are not correct, you can provide the exact sheet, starting (top) cells of both lists and info about how many filled cells there are above the list (U1 & U2). Then I will make sure the formulas is straight copy-past.

Comment: Hi,
I set the name manager it's fine. I put your function in the given cell it's OK. However, I am getting "0" instead of the address which I want. What should I put in the place of "0" in my formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(U1&U2&U3&U4,"N/A+N/A+N/A","")
```

Comment: It won't work, as I want to have the range expandable, but thank you for your hint. It's still applicable for small ranges.