# Unique range in Excel doesn't return the unique record but all other records

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have got a problem with the unique value in Excel.

I used the advice from this query:

[Extract unique value from the range in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325713/extract-unique-value-from-the-range-in-excel)

used the following module:

```
 Public Function unikue(rng As Range)
Dim arr, c As Collection, r As Range
Dim nCall As Long, nColl As Long
Dim i As Long
Set c = New Collection

nCall = Application.Caller.Count

On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng
        c.Add r.Text, CStr(r.Text)
    Next r
On Error GoTo 0
nColl = c.Count


If nCall > nColl Then
    ReDim arr(1 To nCall, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To nCall
        arr(i, 1) = ""
    Next i
Else
    ReDim arr(1 To nColl, 1 To 1)
End If

For i = 1 To nColl
    arr(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
Next i

unikue = arr
End Function
```

And typed the following formula in the cell V15:

```
 {=UNIKUE(U3:U6)}
```

Unfortunately instead of an address, which I want I am getting the prevailing N/A+N/A+N/A values, which I want to get rid of.

I want to have only the address string (bounded red) appearing in the V15 column.

[image]

Apart from the module I tried also created the name manager, where I input this formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$U$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$U:$U)-2,1)
```

and next allocated another formula including this name in the cell V16

```
       =IFERROR(INDEX(List,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($V$23:$V23,List),0)),"")
```

but unfortunately, I am getting the blank cell instead.

How can I solve this problem? In the cell V15, I want to have the only one string, which is other than N/A+N/A+N/A.

Comment: So, if I would understand that you need to extract the unique values from the range "U3:U6" and return them on row 15, starting from the V:V column, up to the next columns, according to the number of unique values found, will it be correct? I mean, in this very case, to be returned "NA+NA+NA" in "V15" and the string starting with "26+Coronation..." In "W15"...

Comment: I would like to extract the unique value from the range U3:U6  and return it in the cell V15. The unique value will be only one always because I consider only 1 address valid at the given time.

Comment: What do you mean by "addres valid"? Don't we speak about strings? Should the process exclude the "NA+NA+NA" string cases?

Comment: Yes, we are speaking about the strings. The address string is different than N/A+N/A+N/A and it must be shown in the cell V15

Comment: What EXCACTLY to be shown in V15? According to what we can see in the attached picture... What string? Not the one starting with "26+Coronation..."?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to see there the string starting from 26+Coronation Villas, which I marked red.

Comment: Now I changed the question in order to clarify.

Comment: So, all "NA+NA+NA" strings will be eliminated, and only the confirmed one will be copied in range V15. Is this "NA+NA+NA" a real string or a result of a formula? Can other similar strings exist instead etc.? I mean only "NA", or "NA+NA"?

Comment: All stuff from the range U3:U6 is the result of the formula, although it's the concatenation result of different cells, where other formulas have been allocated. I want to eliminate all N/A+n/A strings and leave only the string with address in the V15 cell.

Comment: We firstly must tell to VBA what "with address" means... And it would be simpler if we do that by exclusion. So, if all strings containing "NA" are excluded, would it be OK?

Comment: Yes indeed. I would like to exclude all the N/A strings and the string, which is other than N/A (26 coronation villas, etc) I want to have populated in V15 cell.
Next I am setting this cell as a variable with range V15 in VBA, because I need it to have opened in Google Maps.

Comment: OK. Copy the next function in a module. But it is not place here for it, even if it is small. I will post an answer...

Comment: If you have Excel O365 with the `UNIQUE` function, you could use `=UNIQUE(U3:U6,,TRUE)`

Comment: I have got Excel 2016. Will it still be valid?

Comment: Only if you have the `UNIQUE` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please copy the next function in a module:

```
Function UniqueStr(rng As Range) As String
   Dim El As Variant
   For Each El In rng.Value
    If InStr(El, "N/A") = 0 Then UniqueStr = El: Exit Function
   Next
End Function
```

But, if you will have more then one "address valid" in the processed range, the function will return only the first one...

Then, write a formula in the cell you need to receive the returned string:

```
=uniqueStr(U3:U6)
```

After writing the function name, you can select with the cursor the range you need to be processed.

If you need to use an array function, there are two possibilities:

If you need it to increment each range to be processed row (I mean if the first formula will analize "U3:U6", the next row formula will process "U4:U7". The function will use relative reference.

If you need that all the cells having the array formula to process the same "U3:U6" string, please select it in the formula you wrote and press `F4`. In this way the function will use Absolute reference... It will look like this:

```
=uniqueStr($U$3:$U$6)
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need! Now when I change my record and this string address shifts for example from U6 to U4 it's still visible in V15. You are irreplaceable! Thanks, A LOT!

Comment: @MKR: Glad I could help! But you must be a little more focused on the way you ask... :)

Comment: I wish I could you give you more than 10 points today ;) I know about this problem and I will intensively work on it :)

Comment: @MKR: Keep trying! This should be the way. A programmer must not only know a programming language. He must be able to understand what is important fot the task to be accomplished and cultivate his imagination to find a simpler, but optimum solution. This is not my case. It is something valid for everybody trying to program in any language ...

Comment: I know, I always try to answer and ask on this way. Always also I am bringing the solution ASAP knowing, that it might be helpful for someone in the future.