# Excel unique value for range doesn't work for the formula results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

Following this question:

[Unique range in Excel doesn't return the unique record but all other records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342608/unique-range-in-excel-doesnt-return-the-unique-record-but-all-other-records)

I would like to use the following function:

```
 Option Explicit

 Function UniqueStr(Rng As Range) As String
 Dim El As Variant
 For Each El In Rng.Value
 If InStr(El, "N/A") = 0 Then UniqueStr = El: Exit Function
 Next
 End Function
```

for the cells formatted as the time value.

The function is valid for the first record only. When the value other than N/A occurs as the 2nd record, then the function returns #VALUE! as per in the image below:[image].

The situation is the same when I do the formatting of the cells into "General" or "Number".

My range of data is between E372 and E737. To calculate it (extract the valid data) I used the following formula:

```
   =IF(E524=MIN($E$372:$E$737),E524,NA())
```

This means, that when the value is minimum, then the value of the cell is visible. In other situation, it's N/A. The results of this formula were stored in the next range: E741:E1106. Now I want to extract these unique values in one cell by the function described above:

```
 =UniqueStr($E$741:$E$1106)
```

but I am constantly getting the #VALUE instead of the result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are those "N/A" strings or the result of a formula?

Comment: These "N/A" are results of the formula:
=IF(E527=MIN($E$372:$E$737),E527,NA()) - example for cell E527
I think that this might cause the problem.

Comment: Try using ISNA in your function.

Comment: How to incorporate ISNA ot my situation? I see that this is more issue for VLOOKUP